# Running tests after packaging

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jar, package

One of my projects needs a pretty complex setup for the resulting JAR file, so I'd like to run a test after the `package` phase to make sure the JAR contains what it should.

How do I do that with Maven 2?

Comment: Maybe it is worth to have a look at the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) - unfortunately I never used it myself and can't give more information on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your project into a [multi-module build](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects). In the first module, build your original project. In the second module, add a dependency to the first.

This will add the first JAR to the classpath.

---

Update by OP: This works but I had to add this to my POM:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The important part is `<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>`. Without this, my classpath only contained a couple of VM JARs plus the surefire bootstrap JAR (which contains the test classpath in the `MANIFEST.MF`). I have no idea why this test classpath isn't visible from the classes loaded from it.

Comment: test-artefact? Do you mean another module?

Comment: Yes. An additional artefact that will demand the recently build of your lib from the repository and does the checks on it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the surefire-plugin for this. what you need to do is associate a phase with an execution (see below). You will need to change the phase to be whatever you want it to be in your case one after the package phase.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unittests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/**/**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure the packaged jar file will be in the test classpath instead of the compiled classes?

Comment: @K. Clazen: yes, it will be. Run maven with the `-X` argument to inspect the classpath.

Comment: @Robert Munteanu After `Building jar: c:\me\workspaces\default\do-nothing-project\target\do-nothing-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` i get `[DEBUG] Test Classpath :
[DEBUG]   c:\me\workspaces\default\do-nothing-project\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   c:\me\workspaces\default\do-nothing-project\target\classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar` - looks like the compiled classes are in the classpath instead of the jar.

Comment: @K. Claszen : those were my memories, strange that it does not happen this way...

Comment: What do you wish to test about the jar file? Is the jar file executable? Could you run the jar file and test it in its running state? Perhaps run a script via something like exec:exec and check the contents of the jar.

Comment: @Paul Whelan Do not ask me :-) I just thought it would be importend to have the jar file in the classpath instead of the compiled classes and maven resources - otherwise the question does not make many sence to me. Maybe the jar file is populated with other stuff that is important to be available at runtime. And as I see this is not the case with your solution.

Comment: @Paul: I need to test the structure and loading resources from the JAR. So I absolutely need the packaged JAR on the classpath. But if everything fails, I can create an additional classloader.